# error "ODBC driver does not support the requested properties" in excel VBA

Tags: vba, odbc

I am getting error "ODBC driver does not support the requested properties"  in excel VBA on following line of code :
oRs.Open Qry m oConn , adOpenStatic , adLockBatchOptimistic

I am fetching data from a Teradata View.

Also i am not getting this always, it is frequent, sometime it runs okay sometime it fails.

Comment: `adLockBactchOptimistic` - is it a typo in your code or just in your question? Of course you are using `Option Explicit`?

Comment: It was typo in question-- Thanks, Yes I am using Option Explicit